# Style categories block in query loop

Tags: theme-development

Within a query loop I wanted to display the category of the post. Therefore I used the *categories*-block:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I did not find an option to style this block in the *theme.json*. Is it not possible for this block?

Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: can you edit this to just 1 question? You can create new questions if you have more than one but bundling them all together can severely reduce the chance of an answer, as well as the quality and length

Comment: Reduced to the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no option to style this block in the theme.json I remove the underline for every link with the follwing code:

```
  "styles": {
    "link": {
      "typography": {
        "textDecoration": "none"
      }
    }
  }
```